# Не открывается cmd в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, pycharm

В PyCharm не открывается терминал, PyCharm последней актуальной версии, Windows 10 x64. Пробовал запускать от админа, в настройках проекта путь к проекту правильный, путь к `cmd` - `cmd.exe`.

[image: error]

Логи

```
2021-05-20 16:42:59,700 [  64314]   INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start [C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe] in B:\Python\code\bot
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner.lambda$openSessionInDirectory$6(AbstractTerminalRunner.java:243)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:76)
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:50)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:185)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyException: Error starting winpty: agent executable does not exist: 'B:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\pty4j-native\win\x86-64\winpty-agent.exe'
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPty.<init>(WinPty.java:89)
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:73)
```

upd

теперь даже после переустановки PyCharm сразу же крашится консоль с ошибкой `error starting winpty lost connection to agent`, так несколько крашей, после `error starting winpty agent executable does not exist`, а сам файл `winpty-agent.exe` удаляется.

Comment: INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023435/14785750

Comment: @Jack_oS у меня последняя версия, к чему это?

Comment: Я обновил Pycharm и  отпустило

Comment: Помогает временно только переустановка PyCharm, но через время файл `winpty-agent.exe` просто исчезает

Answer (score 3):

Проверьте правильность указания путей к директории проекта и к cmd. Так-же причиной могут стать антивирусные программы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавьте в исключения ативируса файлы

```
B:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\pty4j-native\win\x86-64\winpty-agent.exe
B:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\pty4j-native\win\x86-64\winpty.dll
```

Comment: пути правильные, антивируса нет, в брандмауэре доступ разрешен

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать полный путь к cmd.exe

В основном он `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Я пробовал и полный путь к `cmd` и к `powershell` разницы нет. Проблема в этом файле `winpty-agent.exe`, как мне кажется

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Попробуйте выключить плагины, может быть в них дело

Comment: Плагинов никаких нет, только дефолтные

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас не получится найти выход, то есть альтернативный метод запуска python файла через bash.

1. Установите git bash [для Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.32.0.windows.2/Git-2.32.0.2-64-bit.exe)
2. Настройте по вкусу, если что-то не знаете, лучше оставить, как было.
3. Перезагрузите ПК
4. В PyCharm установите bash.exe вместо cmd.exe
5. Для запуска python файла пишите: `python name.py`

Запасной вариант, если ничего не поможет, не более.

Comment: В таком варианте открывается башевская консоль на секунду и крашится сразу же.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Попробуйте другой компилятор или редактор кода, например vscode, он лишним на ПК не будет. Если проблема иссякнет значит проблемы со стороны JetBrains